# Data frame Assigning returning NaN data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment

I am using a function to return a data frame.
Each column of the data frame is made from certain conditions. If I run the lines for each column separately in the console its working fine but when I use in the function it is returning the data frame with null values

```
def correl(meter,month):
 corr_matrix['Week 1']=data_merge.loc[((data_merge['meter_no']==meter)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==1)&(data_merge['month_y']==month)), 'mean_kw']
 corr_matrix['Week 2']=data_merge.loc[((data_merge['meter_no']==meter)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==2)&(data_merge['month_y']==month)), 'mean_kw']
 corr_matrix['Week 3']=data_merge.loc[((data_merge['meter_no']==meter)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==3)&(data_merge['month_y']==month)), 'mean_kw']
 corr_matrix['Week 4']=data_merge.loc[((data_merge['meter_no']==meter)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==4)&(data_merge['month_y']==month)), 'mean_kw']
 return corr_matrix
m=6    
for i in unique_meter:   
     #plt.plot()
     plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) ##weekly consumption
     plt.plot(data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==1),'day_week_x'],data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==1),'mean_kw'], color='red',  label="Week 1")
     plt.plot(data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==2),'day_week_x'],data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==2),'mean_kw'], color='orange', label="Week 2")
     plt.plot(data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==3),'day_week_x'],data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==3),'mean_kw'], color='blue', label="Week 3")
     plt.plot(data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==4),'day_week_x'],data_merge.loc[(data_merge['meter_no']==i)&(data_merge['month_y']==m)&(data_merge['week_n_x']==4),'mean_kw'], color='green', label="Week 4")
     plt.xlabel('day')
     plt.ylabel('Power Consumption_'+str(i))

     plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) ##correlation check
     plt.matshow((correl(i,m)).corr())
     plt.legend()
     plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(1000,50))
```

My issue is here with data frame corr_matrix

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add some example dataframe to reproduce your question ?